# Ansible: How to loop through 2 var dicts only when hostname corresponds

Tags: loops, ansible, conditional-statements

Im trying to loop to a set of variables depending on the hostname. I cant get the conditional right.

Say i have 2 set of vars:

```
databases_eu:
  - name: database_eu_1
    port: 5432
    login: {{ vault_user_database_eu_1 }}
    password: {{ vault_pw_database_eu_1 }}
  - name: database_eu_2
    port: 5433
    login: {{ vault_user_database_eu_2 }}
    password: {{ vault_pw_database_eu_2 }}
databases_us:
  - name: database_us_1
    port: 5432
    login: {{ vault_user_database_us_1 }}
    password: {{ vault_pw_database_us_1 }}
  - name: database_us_2
    port: 5433
    login: {{ vault_user_database_us_2 }}
    password: {{ vault_pw_database_us_2 }}
```

And i want to loop through it depending on the hostname, how would i do that?

I thought something like below, but im missing the `when` statement:

```
- name: copy configs
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: config.yml.j2
    dest: /opt/db/configs/{{ item.name }}.yml
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: '0644'
  loop: 
    - "{{ databases_eu | inventory_hostname == 'eu.db.example.com' }}" 
    - "{{ databases_us | inventory_hostname == 'us.db.example.com' }}"
```

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "loop through it depending on the hostname."  What is the desired output?  The easiest way to show that would be a `debug` instead of `template`, and what the output of the debug should be with the loop.

Comment: The play should choose the variables depending on the hostname. So I am configuring 4 servers. 2 EU, 2 US. Use the variables databases_eu for servers in EU, use databases_us for server in the US. This way i only need one play(instead of 2 what i dont want) to differentiate between US and EU config and still configure 4 servers. In the real situation i use even more servers, so it gets messy very soon.

Comment: Any reason you cannot simply put the data into `host_vars` files?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [*lookup*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#lookup-plugins) plugin *vars* to get the value of a variable. See

```sh
shell> ansible-doc -t lookup vars
```

There are many options on how to reference the data. For example, given the inventory

```sh
shell> cat hosts
eu.db.example.com
us.db.example.com
```

---

1. **Create a dictionary** of data assigned to the hosts, e.g.

```yaml
    databases_host:
      eu.db.example.com: databases_eu
      us.db.example.com: databases_us
```

Then the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Configure {{ item.name }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('vars', databases_host[inventory_hostname]) }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.name }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [eu.db.example.com] => (item=database_eu_1) => 
  msg: Configure database_eu_1
ok: [us.db.example.com] => (item=database_us_1) => 
  msg: Configure database_us_1
ok: [us.db.example.com] => (item=database_us_2) => 
  msg: Configure database_us_2
ok: [eu.db.example.com] => (item=database_eu_2) => 
  msg: Configure database_eu_2
```

---

2. The next option is to put the **name of the dictionaries to a host-specific variable**, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
eu.db.example.com my_db=databases_eu
us.db.example.com my_db=databases_us
```

Then the playbook below gives the same result

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Configure {{ item.name }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('vars', my_db) }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.name }}"
```

---

3. The next option is to **create the name of the dictionary dynamically**, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Configure {{ item.name }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('vars', my_db) }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.name }}"
      vars:
        my_db: "{{ 'databases_' ~ inventory_hostname.split('.').0 }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I solved by creating a group_vars dir. Thanks for the input.